# Want to loop but variable is not initialized

Tags: java, loops, do-while

My problem starts at the first do-while loop. I want it to ask "Please enter an angle between 0 an 90: " and if the user does input a number between 0 and 90, they have to input the amount of gun powder. Their inputs will go through the physics calculations and if their outcome is not "It's a hit!" then I want them to go back and input the angle and gunpowder again. But the thing is at the

`while (distance - distance2 != 0 || distance - distance2 != 1 || distance2 - distance != 1); System.out.println("It's a hit!");`

> The error says: variable distance2 might not have been initialized.

---

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    public class BombsAway {
    private static double ZERO_THOUSAND = 1000;
    private static double KG_TO_VELOCITY = 50;
    private static double GRAVITY = -9.81;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      DecimalFormat threeDec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
      Random gen = new Random();
      BombsAway distanceAn = new BombsAway();
      boolean invalidInput = true;
      double distance, distance2;

      System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
      while(invalidInput) {
         try {
            int seedValue = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());
            if (seedValue <= 0) {
               System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value:"
                + " ");
            } 
            else {
               distance = gen.nextDouble() * ZERO_THOUSAND;
               System.out.println("That target is " + threeDec.format(distance) 
                + "m away.");  
               do {
               System.out.println("Please enter an angle between 0 and 90 " +
                "degrees: ");
               while (invalidInput) {
                  try {
                     double angle = Double.valueOf(input.nextLine());
                     if (angle < 0 || angle > 90) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter an angle between " +
                         "0 and 90 degrees: ");
                     } 
                     else {
                        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of " + 
                         "gunpowder in kilograms: ");
                        try {
                           double gunpowder = 
                            Double.valueOf(input.nextLine());
                           //physics part
                           double initialV = gunpowder * KG_TO_VELOCITY;
                           double vX = initialV * Math.cos(angle);
                           double vY = initialV * Math.sin(angle);
                           double airBorn = (-vY - vY) / GRAVITY;
                           distance2 = (vX * airBorn);

                           if (distance > distance2) {
                              double finalDist = distance - distance2;
                              System.out.println("It's " +
                               threeDec.format(finalDist) + "m short.");
                           }
                           else if (distance < distance2) {
                              double finalDist = distance2 - distance;
                              System.out.println("It's " + 
                               threeDec.format(finalDist) + "m long.");
                           }
                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                           System.out.println("Please enter the amount of " +
                            "gunpowder in kilograms: ");
                        }
                     }
                  }
                  catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                      System.out.println("Please enter an angle between " +
                       "0 and 90 degrees: ");
                  }
               }
            }while (distance - distance2 != 0 || distance - distance2 != 1
              || distance2 - distance != 1);
                System.out.println("It's a hit!");
            }
         }
         catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try, when you declare it, `distance2 = 0.0;`. Warnings don't lie.

Comment: So initialise it. You shouldn't need to waste time asking questions on the Internet for trivial errors like this. What the compiler has told you is entirely sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code - `distance2` is initialized inside one of the conditional blocks (in `else` block inside `while` loop) there may be cases when your `while` or `else` condition will not be fulfilled and in that case `distance2` is left un-initialized and **Local variables** cannot be used without initialization so simply initialize that `distance2` with any meaningful or required default value as:
`double distance2 = 0.0;` or with some specific value that your code logic works on

Answer (score 2):

The `distance2` variable is initialized in a try/catch block.  It's possible an exception could be thrown, and land the flow of control in the `catch` block before `distance2` is initialized.  After the catch block, distance2 is used in a calculation at the end of the `while` loop, so yes: it might not be initialized at this line:

```
while (distance - distance2 == 0 || distance - distance2 == 1
      || distance2 - distance == 1)
```

if a `NumberFormatException` was thrown when you are reading the `gunpowder` or `angle` values from `input`.  There is also an if condition (bounds check on `angle`) that could leave distance2 unset.

Comment: case of try catch is far away - as it first needs to pass if else condition

Comment: Very true...there are multiple ways that `distance2` could wind up unset!